# IOS UI Design (colours & button images). During or after writing?

Tags: ios, user-interface, skinning

Can you 'skin' an iOS app by designing whole screens in a graphical editor and overlaying these onto your app screens, or do you have to apply images, colour etc to each UI element individually? (I know that the first approach would be a pain should you wish to move things around later).

Comment: While this may be an interesting topic, it is not a suitable question for SO in that there is no objectively "right" answer.

Comment: OK thanks. I could probably have phrased it "Can I skin my app by adding images etc either during or after the programming phase, or is there a better way to do it? Obviously fairly new to iOS programming.